# integrating scikit-learn with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I'm exploring pyspark and the possibilities of integrating scikit-learn with pyspark. I'd like to train a model on each partition using scikit-learn. That means, when my RDD is is defined and gets distributed among different worker nodes, I'd like to use scikit-learn and train a model (let's say a simple k-means) on each partition which exists on each worker node. As scikit-learn algorithms takes a Pandas dataframe, my initial idea was to call `toPandas` for each partition and then train my model. However, the `toPandas` function collects the DataFrame into the driver and this is not something that I'm looking for. Is there any other way to achieve such a goal?

Comment: If I can somehow convert each partition to a dataframe into an array-like structure, that is possible, right?

Comment: I don't see how is it relevant to compute a model on each partition. What does even mean ? In practice, how do you assemble models ?

Comment: so let's say if I run a kmeans on each partition, then somehow I should transfer all the centroid point to the driver. This would be like an approximate k-means. However, I don't know how to transfer the centroid points to the driver now. Any idea?

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. Those centroids were trained considering a certain vector space. You can't just take them and perform a average or so.

Comment: And if you want to use Kmeans, why don't you use spark's implementation directly ?

Comment: I agree that this won't be the best solution but the main reason to do such a thing is to see how I can integrate scikit-learn with pyspark. So, I'm not looking for the best clustering.
Having said that, do you think we can somehow use k-means (or any other clustering or classification) in that way? That is, how to convert each partition to an array-like structure?

Comment: This question is getting quite broad. First, you can't integrate scikit-learn with spark in that way. Second, no, you still can't use clustering methods in that way, it doesn't make any sense. I won't answer the third one because array-like structure can be an RDD, it can be anything, so that doesn't make any sense as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34438829/1560062 - but @eliasah is right here. Having weak models won't get you anywhere alone especially when you're interested in unsupervised learning.

Answer (score 9):

scikit-learn can't be fully integrated with spark as for now, and the reason is that scikit-learn algorithms aren't implemented  to be distributed as it work just on a single machine.

Nevertheless, you can find ready to use Spark - Scikit integration tools in [spark-sklearn](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn) that supports (for the moments) executing GridSearch on Spark  for cross validation.

**Edit**

As of 2020 the [spark-sklearn](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn) is deprecated and the [joblib-spark](https://github.com/joblib/joblib-spark) is the recommended successor of it. Based on the documentation you can easily distribute a cross validation to a Spark cluster like this:

```py
from sklearn.utils import parallel_backend
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from joblibspark import register_spark

register_spark() # register spark backend

iris = datasets.load_iris()
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
with parallel_backend('spark', n_jobs=3):
  scores = cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)

print(scores)
```

A GridSearchCV can be distributed in the same way.

Comment: what if I want to execute an arbitrary model? let's say run a kmeans on each partition. Is that supported in spark-sklearn?

Comment: This library supports just distributed grid search last time I've checked. And it still seems the case now. Unfortunately, distributing algorithms isn't just a plug and play or it would have been very easy. Unless sklearn implements those algorithms directly on spark, it wouldn't be possible to integrate that easy.

Comment: What about on a notebook? Let's say we are going to do something integrating Sklearn and PySpark on Colab. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

no, scikit learn doesn't work with pyspark & reason being scikit learn is a package which will work an individual computer whereas spark is a distributed environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pandas_filter_func(iterator):
    for pandas_df in iterator:
        yield pandas_df[pandas_df.a == 1]

df.mapInPandas(pandas_filter_func, schema=df.schema).show()
```

Took it from here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_df.html#Applying-a-Function