# is Dataframe.toPandas always on driver node or on worker nodes?

Tags: python, hadoop, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Imagine you are loading a large dataset by the SparkContext and Hive. So this dataset is then distributed in your Spark cluster. For instance a observations (values + timestamps) for thousands of variables.

Now you would use some map/reduce methods or aggregations to organize/analyze your data. For instance grouping by variable name.

Once grouped, you could get all observations (values) for each variable as a timeseries Dataframe. If you now use DataFrame.toPandas

```
def myFunction(data_frame):
   data_frame.toPandas()

df = sc.load....
df.groupBy('var_name').mapValues(_.toDF).map(myFunction)
```

1. is this converted to a Pandas Dataframe (per Variable) on each
   worker node, or
2. are Pandas Dataframes always on the driver node and the data is therefore transferred from the worker nodes to the driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special about Pandas `DataFrame` in this context.

- If `DataFrame` is created by using `toPandas` method on `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` [this collects data and creates local Python object on the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991297/1560062).
- If `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` is created inside executor process ([for example in `mapPartitions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445113/1560062)) you simply get `RDD[pandas.core.frame.DataFrame]`. There is no distinction between Pandas objects and let's say a `tuple`.
- Finally pseudocode in you example couldn't work becasue you cannot create (in a sensible way) Spark `DataFrame` (I assume this what you mean by `_.toDF`) inside executor thread.

Comment: So you could use the Pandas Dataframe API for instance within a map function in order to use its more convo enemy methods even in the worker node. for instance doing some analytics for just that information in the map step and return the result.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, in a similar as SparkR `dapply`. Getting desired performance can be tricky though so you'll have to balance resource allocation and parallelism.

Comment: You're my hero. I'm still a newbie but improving. Maybe you can help me out with [that one, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155954/how-to-do-a-nested-for-each-loop-with-pyspark).

Comment: Depends on how you create it, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47716346/843463